# How to get array from string contained identical symbols in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have string like this: "1112222355". How can I get array like that ["111","2222","3","55"] using Ruby?

Comment: `"112211"` would be `["11, "22", "11"]`?

Comment: @Kashyap, exactly, that's what I meant, it's not clear if the OP wants to group all or only consecutives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to group only consecutive elements, use [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
> "1112222355".chars.chunk { |x| x }.map { |c, cs| cs.join }
=> ["111", "2222", "3", "55"]
```

Comment: `chunk { |x| x }` is why I added something to Facets that trans suggested for inclusion in 2.0: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6373

Answer (score 1):

```
"1112222355".scan(/((.)\2*)/).map(&:first)
# => ["111", "2222", "3", "55"]
```